# Find asymptotic behavior of recurrence $T(n) =T(n-2) + 1/\ln n$

Tags: algorithms, summation, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve this recurrence:  $T(n) =T(n-2) + 1/\ln n$. And I can't make progress on.

What I did so far:

$$ \frac{1}{\ln(n - 2i)} = 1 \\ \ln(n-2i) = 1 \\ n - 2i = 2 \\ i = \frac{n-2}{2} $$

$ n' = i $, that is, n' is the tree's height.

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n'} \frac{1}{\ln(n-2i)} \\ \sum_{i=1}^{n'+1} \frac{1}{\ln(2i)} $$

So, I'm stuck in here. Looks like that the correct answer is $ \theta(\ln(\ln(n)) $ by using the harmonic series, but I don't know how to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$T(n) = T(n - 2) + \frac {1}{\ln n}$$

So 
$$T(n) = \sum_{k}^{n/2} \frac{1}{\ln(2k)}$$

which will have the same asymptotic behavior as:

$$\begin{align}
T(n) &\approx \int^{n/2} \frac{1}{\ln(2k)} ~{\rm d}k\\
&= -\frac 12 \Gamma(0,  -\ln(n))/2 \\
&= \frac 12 E_1(\ln(n))
\end{align}$$

Where $\Gamma(,)$ is the [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Special_values) and $E_1()$ is the [Exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).  [So bounds can be established with](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Exponential_and_logarithmic_behavior:_bracketing)

$$\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\,\ln\!\left( 1+\frac{2}{x} \right)
< \mathrm{E_1}(x) <
e^{-x}\,\ln\!\left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)
\qquad x>0
$$

Comment: @DanielIV: Thanks for answer. This can't be solved only with summations?

Comment: @meitcher Solved or verified? If you can harness an epiphany to guess the answer, then you can (probably) verify the answer using the definition of asymptotic behavior (Big-O, Theta, etc).

Comment: @DanielIV: verified. Can I do this then? $ \sum_{i=2}^{n/2} \frac{1}{lg(i)} = O(lg(lg(n)) $. Btw, nice thinking using integral. I didn't know that summations can be represented by integral.